# Keep items in inventory on death in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I once played a vanilla Minecraft adventure map (called "Herobrine's Mansion") that prevented the player from losing their items on death. Which commands can be used to prevent the player from losing their items on death (in vanilla Minecraft)?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the command `/gamerule keepInventory true` (case sensitive) to prevent the player from losing items on death. This command will work in Vanilla Minecraft, without using any mods (as long as cheats are enabled). You can also do this on a server as long as you have operator status.

Comment: only if cheats are enabled

Comment: Someone edited my answer and added "you are OP'ed" to this answer. I'm not even sure what this is intended to mean: does it mean "overpowered", or does it mean something else?

Comment: it means that you have [OPerator](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Op) privileges, essentially the moderators of your server

Comment: Command blocks don't have to be enabled.

Answer (score 6):

Use `/gamerule keepinventory true`. This'll make you keep your inventory when you die.

As mentioned before, you need to have cheats enabled, and you need to have the permissions to execute them.

Assuming you're in creative and have cheats enabled:

- Enter the command `/gamerule keepinventory`
- (Enter command `/gamemode survival` or `/gamemode adventure`) --> Takes you out of Creative

And you're done.

Assuming you're in Survival:

- Hit pause, and click open to LAN.
- On the next screen, set "Allow Cheats" to "ON."
- Enter the command `/gamerule keepInventory`
- Save and Exit.
  When you re-open your map, items will stay in your inventory after you die.

Comment: `Save and Exit. When you re-open your map, items will stay in your inventory after you die.`   So it’s a persistent setting that only has to be set once? ఠ_ఠ