# Minecraft keep inventory not working in 1.16.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I executed the command `/gamerule keepInventory true` and when I test this with `/gamerule keepInventory`, this command returns true.
However, sometimes when me or my friends die we lose our stuff and sometimes we don't. No one else is op apart from me. It has lead to us losing our stuff a ton of times. What is wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep items in inventory on death in Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94189/keep-items-in-inventory-on-death-in-minecraft)

Comment: no, @aphid, it doesn't. he knows the command, the command isn't working.

Comment: Maybe https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/144326/minecraft-gamerule-keepinventory/144327 could help, noticing the wrong case-sensitivity of the test command? There's too many duplicates for this; googling finds 5+ results.

Comment: This may not be the solution, but gamerules don't apply across dimensions, so setting keepInventory to true in the overworld doesn't automatically apply to the nether or the end.

Comment: In case this gets closed, I think the most upvoted answer is valuable, so maybe we can edit the question to reflect that (I know, very much against SE regulations)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a server like me, and you are using paper, it's because the world file of Overworld, Nether and The End are seperated, which means each world has its own gamerules. So you have to execute the command at each dimension.

Answer (score -1):

In 1.16 this command does not work in the nether. You have to use a respawning anchor. If you don't have one in the nether, you lose all you items.